# Differentiation of tr$(AD^{-3\alpha}B)$ with respect to scalar $\alpha$, $D$ is positive diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, trace

Please, may I know how to differentiate tr$(AD^{-3\alpha}B)$ with respect to scalar $\alpha$. I'm thinking of an approach with the Frobenius inner product, but I'm not conversant with the rules. I'm open to any convenient approach. Thanks.

Edit:  Let $D$ be positive diagonal so we can have negative powers of $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
L &= \log(D),\quad \beta = -3\alpha \cr
}$$
One nice thing about diagonal matrices is that they can be manipulated almost like scalars. Consider the following diagonal matrix function and its differential.
$$\eqalign{
F &= D^\beta = \exp(\beta L) \cr
dF &= FL\,d\beta = -3FL\,d\alpha \cr
}$$
Write the trace function in terms of the Frobenius (:) product and the $F$-function.
Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}(BAF) = BA:F \cr
d\phi &= BA:dF = -3BA:FL\,d\alpha \cr
\frac{d\phi}{d\alpha} &= -3BA:FL \cr
}$$
**NB:**   You stated that the $D$-matrix was non-negative, but that's not good enough. For the logarithm (or negative powers) to make sense, there can be no zeros on its diagonal.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question so that $D$ be taken to be positive diagonal, for negative powers to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, all that is needed is a systematic application of the chain rule in multiple dimensions. Hopefully you are familiar with differentiation as explained in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds or Loomis and Sternberg's [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf). The notation I'll use is very close to both these books. So for example,

> If $V$ and $W$ are (finite-dimensional) normed vector spaces, and $f:V \to W$ is differentiable at a point $a \in V$, (refer to either of those books for a precise definition) then $Df_a$ shall denote the derivative of $f$ evaluated at the point $a$. This is a linear map from $V$ to $W$. So $Df_a(h)$ means the derivative of $f$ at $a$ evaluated at the point $h$.

Then you need to know the chain rule: \begin{equation}
D(f \circ g)_a = Df_{g(a)} \circ Dg_a,
\end{equation} 
and also that if $T: V \to W$ is a linear map then for any $a \in V$, $DT_a = T$. With all of this preliminary stuff out of the way, to solve your question define the following maps:

- $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $F(\alpha) = \text{tr}(AD^{-3\alpha}B)$
- The "left-multiplication by $A$" map defined by $L_A(X) = AX$, where $X$ is a matrix of appropriate size.
- The "right-multiplication by $B$" map defined by $R_B(X) = XB$, where $X$ is a matrix of appropriate size.
- $f: \mathbb{R} \to M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ (if $D$ is $n \times n$), defined by $f(\alpha) = D^{-3\alpha}$.

You wish to calculate $F'(\alpha)$, so we first begin by writing $F$ as a composition of $4$ functions:
\begin{align}
F(\alpha) = (\text{tr} \circ L_A \circ R_B \circ f)(\alpha).
\end{align}
So, by a direct application of the Chain rule, (and it's corollary; see Chapter 3, Theorem 7.2 in Loomis and Sternberg), we can calculate $F'(\alpha)$ by the formula:
\begin{equation}
F'(\alpha) = \left[D(\text{tr})_{(L_A\circ R_B \circ f)(\alpha)} \circ D(L_A)_{(R_B \circ f)(\alpha)} \circ D(R_B)_{f(\alpha)} \right] \left( f'(\alpha) \right)
\end{equation}
i.e $F'(\alpha)$ is the composition of those $3$ linear maps applied to $f'(\alpha)$.
Notice that $\text{tr}, L_A, R_B$ are linear maps, so they are their own derivatives. Hence,
\begin{align}
F'(\alpha) &= \left[\text{tr} \circ L_A \circ R_B \right] \left( f'(\alpha) \right) \\
&= \text{tr} \left( A \cdot f'(\alpha) \cdot B \right)
\end{align}
To compute $f'(\alpha)$, you just differentiate each entry of $D^{-3\alpha}$ with respect to $\alpha$. So if $D = \text{diag}(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ then
\begin{align}
f'(\alpha) &= \text{diag}(-3 \text{log}(x_1) x_1^{-3\alpha}, \dots, -3 \text{log}(x_n) x_n^{-3\alpha}) \\
&= -3 \text{log}(D) \cdot D^{-3\alpha}
\end{align}

So, finally,we get

> \begin{equation}
> F'(\alpha) = -3 \text{tr} \left[A \cdot \text{log}(D) \cdot D^{-3\alpha} \cdot B \right]
> \end{equation}